# Deep copy Javascript array with properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using `.slice()`, I can deep copy a Javascript Array of primitive types, for example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var newArr = arr.slice();
newArr.push(5);
console.log(arr); // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(newArr); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

However, If I add a property to `arr` like so:

```
arr.prop1 = 5;
```

and do the same:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.prop1 = 8;
arr.prop2 = 9;
var newArr = arr.slice();
newArr.push(5);
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, prop1: 9, prop2: 8]
console.log(newArr); //  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The property values do not carry over to `newArr`

I have considered not using `.slice()` and looping over the property values of `arr` instead, assigning them to `newArr`, using :

```
for (var key in arr) {
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    newArr[key] = arr[key];
  }
}
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, prop1: 9, prop2: 8]
console.log(newArr); //  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, prop1: 9, prop2: 8]
```

Is this going to be the quickest way to deep copy these arrays with properties? Is there in easier or cleaner way I can do this using `.slice()` or another array method? I am doing this operation tens of thousands of times and want it to be as clean and efficient as possible

Comment: Why you're using an array if you should be using an object instead?

Comment: Whether this is good enough depends on whether you are expecting prototyped properties/methods to be available in `newArr`.

Comment: @Andreas I am using an array because I want to be able to maniputate the array data [1,2,3,4] using array methods. It is already part of an object and currently gets copied using `.slice()`. I think that if I nest the array inside an object inside another object, my code gets messy and is harder to maintain, I also think that I am slowing down in terms of processing. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I would like the properties to be available in `newArr` I don't need any methods to be copied. I would just like to copy primitive types over

Comment: @Andreas could you tell me how you would approach this problem using an object and what the benefits would be?

Comment: @Shanimal I think that would work if I wasn't doing the copy so many times, correct me if I'm wrong put I think parsing and stringifying is quite computationally expensive

Comment: Actually the operations are pretty fast, but it sadly doesn't pickup the new properties :( You can try `Object.create` instead, that works for me

Comment: Check RomanPerekhrest's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix an array and object(to make an array behave like an object).
JavaScript *array* has **numeric** indexed items.
 
JavaScript *object* has **string** indexed items.

Arrays have a *length* property that tells how many items are in the array and is automatically updated when you add or remove items to the array.
But ...

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4], newArr = arr.slice();
arr.prop1 = 7;

console.log(arr.length);
```

The output is `4`, though you would expect it to be `5`.
But `arr.prop1 = 7` does not actually add to the array.
Setting a string parameter adds to the *underlying object*.
The *length* property is only modified when you add an item to the array, not the underlying object.
The expression `newArr = arr.slice()` assigns a new array to `newArr`, so it remains an array and behaves like a *pure* array.

> The property values do not carry over to newArr

If you still want to proceed using mixed numeric/string indexed sequences, cloning them, try using `Object.assign()` function. This should be the easiest way for your case:

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object.

```
console.log(Object.assign(newArr, arr));
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, prop1: 7]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @RomanPekerhrest I really like this answer, although the reason I want to attach properties to this array is so that I don't have to `.filter()` the array over and over to `splice()` values from it, I can use the properties as a sort of meta data so I can just `splice()` using index values. This means that having the length unaltered by the properties is exactly why I want them. I will have a look into `object.assign()` it looks very promising. Thank you!

Comment: So have `var myObj = { props: {prop1:7}, arr:[1,2,3,4]}`

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Object.create(proto)`

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.prop1 = 8;
arr.prop2 = 9;
var newArr = Object.create(arr);

newArr.prop1 = 12;
console.log(arr.prop1) // 8
console.log(newArr.prop1) // 12
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: np. it looks like it might have to be shimmed with `__proto__` for < Opera 11.60, but nobody uses an old version of Opera for anything but testing. good luck. :)